# Creating a Brokered Windows Runtime Component in VS 2017?

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently reading through a guide published about a year ago on how to create Brokered Windows Runtime Component for a Windows 10 UWP app that I would like to sideload and utilize the namespaces that are disabled normally in UWP apps. There are a couple steps that I feel this guide explains very vaguely, and I was looking to see if someone could elaborate as to what specific steps I'd need to take to accomplish what I'm looking to do:

The guide is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps)

(Here are the steps I'm confused about from the guide)

> Step 2: Edit the project file manually to change the output type of
>   project to Windows Runtime Component
>
> To do this in Visual Studio, right click on the newly created project
>   and select “Unload Project”, then right click again and select “Edit
>   EnterpriseServer.csproj” to open the project file, an XML file, for
>   editing.
>
> In the opened file, search for the tag and change its value to
>   “winmdobj”.

Which tag? What value needs to be changed?

> Step 3: Create a build rule that creates a "reference" Windows
>   metadata file (.winmd file). i.e. has no implementation.
>
> Step 4: Create a build rule that creates an "implementation" Windows
>   metadata file, i.e. has the same metadata information, but also
>   includes the implementation.

Where would I find information on how to do these steps? I'm assuming that since they're outlined at a very high level, there's probably instructions elsewhere on how to do this, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: The OutputType element.  The "build rules" are clumsy wording for  post-build events, a sample of which is provided.  The mystique is pretty high for anybody that has never used COM before and decent docs are not easy to find.  There are videos, [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9RfF3fW2HI) ought to be good for step-by-step, [this one](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/HarryPierson/Brokered-WinRT-Components-Wake-On-Callback-Demo) provides high-level background.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks!